# Server side rendering with create-inferno-app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, infernojs

I am attempting to set up a server-side implementation of create-inferno-app.
So, i initially run the create-inferno-app to create a sample project and run the `npm start run` and everything looks fine.
This is my `index.js`

```
import { render } from 'inferno';
import App from './App';
render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

and this is `App.js`

```
import { renderToString } from 'inferno-server';
import './App.css';

const App = function({ color = 'red', name }) {
  return (
    <div style={{ color }}>
      Hello
      <span>{name}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
export default renderToString(<App color="blue" name="world" />)
```

I get an error `TypeError: type is not a function`

So how should i use the `renderToString` method in create-inferno-app ?

Answer (score 0):

This `import App from './App';` is importing this `export default renderToString(<App color="blue" name="world" />)` from your app.js.

You want to have your files like this:

**index.js**

```
import { render } from 'inferno';
import App from './App';
render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**app.js**

```
import './App.css';

App = function({ color = 'red', name }) {
  return (
    <div style={{ color }}>
      Hello
      <span>{name}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App
```

**server.js**

```
import { renderToString } from 'inferno-server';
import App from './App';
cosnt appAsString = renderToString(<App color="blue" name="world" />)
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it is throwing error,  `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`. I tried with `require`, then it shows `SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`.

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import` is problem with es6 on your server`

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` is problem with jsx most likely on your server too